# Load specific component from MDL using webpack

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, material-design-lite, sass-loader

I want to just use the layout component of MDL into my project.

So, in my `app.css` file, I am importing this:

`@import url('~material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss');`

and during the building process I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../variables in /Users/Mitch/Documents/project/web/node_modules/material-design-lite/src/layout
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss 3:10-66

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../mixins in /Users/Mitch/Documents/project/web/node_modules/material-design-lite/src/layout
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss 4:10-63
```

`_layout.sccs` starts with these lines

```
@import "../variables";
@import "../mixins";
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

#### Relevant parts of my `webpack.config.js` :

```
const PATHS = {
    node_modules: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build'),
    js: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
    css: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'css'),
};

...
resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve(__dirname),
        PATHS.node_modules,
        PATHS.js,
        PATHS.css
    ],
    ...
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss']
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules!sass')
        },
        {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        },
        {
            test: /\.jpg$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.gif$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
        },
        {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
        },
        {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'file'
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }
    ]
}
...
```

#### Relevant dependencies :

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "eslint": "^3.6.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-validator": "^2.2.7"
}
...
```

## Update

I tried to `@import url('~material-design-lite/src/material-design-lite.scss');`, since this is not a partial, after I modified it to only import the layout component.

Now I am getting the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/material-design-lite/src/material-design-lite.scss
Module build failed: Unknown word (19:1)

  17 | /* Material Design Lite */
  18 | 
> 19 | // Variables and mixins
     | ^
  20 | @import "variables";
  21 | @import "mixins";
  22 | 

 @ ./~/css-loader!./public/css/app.css 3:10-114
```

It fails on the comments. I have no idea how to fix this, I tried using the `postcss` and `postcss-scss` loaders and `postcss-strip-inline-comments` plugin to no avail; the old errors were simply replaced by new errors.

Comment: Can this be related to fact that the file I want to load is a partial? According to the docs: "A partial is simply a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know that the file is **only a partial file** and that **it should not be generated into a CSS file.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem in your example was that you were importing MDL like this

```
@import url('~material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss');
```

instead of

```
@import '~material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss';
```

The first is ignored by the sass-loader (because SASS does not have url() imports) and will be processed by the css-loader. The css-loader, however, will not automatically expand `.scss` to `variables`, for instance. That's why you were getting these "Module not found" errors.

Comment: First of all: How the hell did I not think of this, when my 'solution' does this and some more. How the brain works sometimes.. Thanks. I noticed something however. Consider that the order of contents in my `app.css` file is like this: SASS imports, CSS imports, rest of CSS, When I build the files, the contents of my `app.bundle.css` are in this order: CSS imports, SASS imports, rest of CSS. Is there any way to make it respect the order with which I am importing the files? Because with CSS, in most cases, the ordering is important.

Comment: Sorry to be bothering you but could you please tell me if there is a way to resolve the issue I am facing when I follow the solution you proposed? Y our solution is better than mine and I'd like to implement it, except for that one thing

Comment: The order of resolved imports should be in the same order as the imports are encountered. If that's not the case, there might be another problem in your setup. Could you give me a small example repository that demonstrates it?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/mkarajohn/load_order_example. Check out what the first comment inside `app.scss` reads. When I build it the first comment in my `main.bundle.css` starts with `This marks the beginning of other.css rules`

Comment: Hey Johannes, any chance you may check out the repo I created for you? Thanks.

Comment: `@import` with `css` extensions will not be compiled by the sass-loader, but the css-loader. Just omit the `.css` and the sass-loader will treat the CSS file as SASS file and import it in the correct order.

Comment: I'll be damned, that was it. Thank you very much. Marking this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround.

What I did was that I created a `custom-mdl.scss` file in my `css/` dir, where I simply do

`@import '~material-design-lite/src/layout/_layout.scss';`

and modified my entry point to be like

```
app : [ 'app.js', 'custom-mdl.scss', 'app.css' ]
```

instead of just

```
app : [ 'app.js', 'app.css' ]
```

The above builds fine, with the `custom-mdl` output preceding the `app.css` content in the bundle, as intended.

Note that I also removed the `?modules` from my `ExtractTextPlugin` configuration, so

`ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')`

instead of

`ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules!sass')`

Otherwise the classnames of the `custom-mdl.scss` file come out garbled.